# net/http: Does DetectContentType support JavaScript?

Tags: http, go, mime-types, content-negotiation

DetectContentType, JavaScript support ?

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/c3931ab1b7bceddc56479d7ddbd7517d244bfe17/src/net/http/sniff.go#L21

Is there a genuine reason behind the http Method **DetectContentType** to not support **JavaScript** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the doc comment notes, `DetectContentType` implements the algorithm described at https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/, which does not detect JavaScript. The question then becomes: why doesn't it?

The answer is given in the introduction of the spec:

> These security issues are most severe when an "honest" server allows potentially malicious users to upload their own files and then serves the contents of those files with a low-privilege MIME type. For example, if a server believes that the client will treat a contributed file as an image (and thus treat it as benign), but a user agent believes the content to be HTML (and thus privileged to execute any scripts contained therein), an attacker might be able to steal the user’s authentication credentials and mount other cross-site scripting attacks. (Malicious servers, of course, can specify an arbitrary MIME type in the Content-Type header field.)
>
> This document describes a content sniffing algorithm that carefully balances the compatibility needs of user agent with the security constraints imposed by existing web content.

Labelling untrusted input as JavaScript when it's not (or even when it is!) could lead to security disasters.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, any suggestions how to handle this if for example a pwa or static page with frequently changing js files should be served ?

Maybe generate a index of the trusted js files pre serving and set the content type accordingly ?

Comment: If the server code and JS is trusted, you can just check for the `.js` file extension, right? See https://pkg.go.dev/mime#TypeByExtension for a more general solution.

Comment: Well yes all files form the static folder are indeed trusted, I guess that's a good solution. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Mb175, why can't the server deliver these JS assets while correctly setting `Content-Type` header field in its responses?

Comment: @kostix currently I'm using "http" ServeHTTP it does not set the headers and there is now way to enable it afaik, correct me if im wrong. I solved my problem by setting the headers on the writer which im passing to the ServeHTTP

Comment: @kostix okay never mind the ServeHTTP function does set headers, well I need them for gzip compression it wasn't working in the morning strangely enough now it does. Thanks for the input. So it looks like there is no need to set the header manually in my case at all.